# How to Increase the quality of the Images on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics

I work with Adobe Illustrator creative suite 3.

I want to know how can one really Increase the quality of the Image's / graphics?

because the thing Is,whenever I view the Image or the graphic In Illustrator the graphic Is crisp and really sharp (because Illustrator Is a vector based software,I know that) but when I save the Image In a jpeg/gif or a png the quality dramatically decreases.

I want to know Is there a way to preserve the quality of an image after saving the image?
should I save the image In a particular extension? change the color setting?
what should I do.

Answer (score 6):

What you're experiencing is the most easily perceived difference between vector and raster images. While the former describes shapes in an abstract way, the latter deal with images as a collection of rectangular dots, called pixels.

You can surely export the images in a larger resolution which raises the quality at the expense of file size. But if you want to retain the quality of the output then you shouldn't use JPEG or PNG but rather a file format capable of representing vector graphics. If it's for printing then PDF is usually a choice most companies can work with. Besides, it's the native format for Illustrator anyway.

Side note: You don't really want to export vector graphics in a file format like JPEG anyway because JPEG is primarily intended for photographic images. A direct consequence is that JPEG performs extraordinarily bad with line drawings, sharp edges and high contrast which is not uncommon with vector graphics. PNG is a much better choice here if you need a raster format and usually even compresses such images better.

Comment: +1 But also remember that both GIF and JPEG are lossy compression formats.

Comment: So what your saying Is I should use the .pdf extension to preserve the quality of the Image? Right?

Thanks.

Comment: Parastar: You should use the proper *file format*. While the extension indicates a particular format saving a JPEG image as `.pdf` won't gain you anything.

Comment: You should always save the original file in Illustrator format, and export a copy to the correct format for the intended purpose. Beyond that, you'll need to adjust the export settings for the best quality for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

With version CS5, Illustrator now lets you snap to the pixel grid. If you enable snapping (View > Snap to Pixel) and pixel preview (View > Pixel Preview), your graphics will export nicely as raster images. You can even see the pixel grid automatically when you zoom in really close, just like Photoshop.

You can also use Fireworks, which was essentially designed for this purpose. You can draw more or less the way you would in Illustrator, but everything is rendered as pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is correct to preserve the vector resizable capabilities of an illustration, as it is saved in pdf, SVG, EPS & even the native Ai extension, but if you want to reopen it in a pixel program like Photoshop your best option is to create your actual size canvas, then copy your vector art to it and paste in photoshop as "inteligent object, then adjust the final posiion and size, after that you migh raster that, so you've, decided how the image is set up for your purpose.

or either save your illustration to a bitmap image, but use a maximum resolution profile or rather to use 300 dpi (recomended for standard printing).

However its necessary to think about the convenience of getting to pixels or still working in vectors, maybe you only wanted to make a layout or a sample of your vector work, so your best option is to preserve your original vector file and export the sample in a medium resolution pixel image.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have recently found out is that when working with raster images in Illustrator, is that Illustrator scales down these images automaticaly.
You can set a custom resolution for your images by clicking on Object -> rasterize...